# Making a line list for a RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox, richtextbox

I'm making a text editor and I want to have a line list like other programs.
And I wrote this code(I used a `ListBox` control to make this):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    On Error Resume Next
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Then
        If TextBox1.Lines.Count > 1 Then
            ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1)
        End If
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Lines.Count + 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

But there these problems.

- First: when I press backspace while removing text it removes the line number
- Second: Sometimes when I remove a line and then add another it starts randomly at 1 and then 3 and sometimes 1,4

My Line Counter Starts at 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach does not work properly because you don't account for every possible case, such as copy and pasting, as well as counting all backspaces as a line removal, which obviously is not accurate. A better approach would be using `TextChanged` event instead of `KeyDown` event. You could then keep track of the line count in a variable, and when it changes, you update your `ListBox`.

```
Private lineCount As Integer = 0

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If lineCount < TextBox1.Lines.Count Then
        For i As Integer = lineCount + 1 To TextBox1.Lines.Count
            ListBox1.Items.Add(i)
        Next
    ElseIf lineCount > TextBox1.Lines.Count Then
        For i As Integer = TextBox1.Lines.Count To lineCount - 1
            ListBox1.Items.Remove(i + 1)
        Next
    End If
    lineCount = TextBox1.Lines.Count
End Sub
```